# How to find the assigned value to a variable inside a function on console in R

Tags: r, function

Suppose I have a small function in R

```
 getsum <- function(a, b){ 
       c <- a+b
   }
```

Now when I run this function, It runs rormally. But my question is can I check the assigned value to `c` on console? I know that:

1. I can print its value within function, which will get reflected on console
2. I can return this value via `return` keyword.

I don't want any of these. My question is specifically, whether I can check the value of variables inside a function at console. I tried `functionname::variablename`, but it is not working

Comment: Why do you have `int a`? You don't need to specify the type of your arguments.

Comment: Sorry, It was by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a couple of answers I could give here, I'm not positive what you need it for.

(EDIT: oh, and FYI, I would avoid using "c" as a variable name, that's a function, the ambiguous value is bad. R will compensate by using the value in your current environment, but that's a stopgap measure)

The easiest would be to assign some variable:

```
x <- NULL
```

at the global environment level, and then, somewhere, during the function:

```
x <<- c
```

the double arrow assigns the value to the topmost environment.

However, this is a bit dangerous, as it's going to run as far up as it can to assign that variable. If you're after debugging, then I recommend adding:

```
browser()
```

inside the code somewhere, it will stop execution during the function and then you can run whatever you like inside the function environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug your code, just use RSTUDIO https://www.rstudio.com/ is an IDE with debugging capabilities. In Rstudio setting a breakpoint inside your function and can check the value of internal variables in the right panels.